# How do I get the object keys and values from Reacts searchParams?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

We're working on a react project where some data is passed as a url param. We know the key is 'task' but we don't know what the value is, which is passed as an object.

Here's the code:

```
const ClientRawData = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(searchParams.get(`task`)));

  const data = [searchParams.get(`task`)];

  return (
    <div>
      This is the raw Data: <br></br>
      <div className='users'>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <div className='user'>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClientRawData;
```

No matter how we seem to tackle this, we can only get [object Object] rendered by React.

We have tried:

1. JSON.stringify
2. Enclosing in an array
3. Object.keys / Object.values

Everything gives only a variation of [object Object].

How do we flatten this object and see the key values pairs within?

Comment: please add a copy of the url

Comment: We don't know it in advance...... Only that ?task=[object Object]

Comment: @Cheetara without seeing url or reproduction of problem how we say what you done wrong.

Comment: Does the url literally contain `?task=[object Object]`?

Comment: @James errr....possibly  You're a genius, client needs to stringify it ....

Answer (score 0):

`?task=[object Object]` means that the way that set `task` query param is not correct, it just turns it to string, you need to use `encodeURIComponent` method to encode the special characters correctly.

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent